# CakePHP working on local but can't get it work on production

Tags: php, cakephp-2.3

I have an issue making my cakephp project work on my shared hosting server.
I followed all the needed steps so it can work on local, and it's working. Once I upload on the server, in a specific domain name, only the homepage works, once I want to call another controller, i get the "404 - File or directory not found." error.

the project is hosted at : [fme.tahrijouti.com](http://fme.tahrijouti.com/). the domain redirects to the webroot folder in the cakephp structure.

My controller is : posts. I can make it work if I change the URL by specifying the controller & action, you can see it [here](http://fme.tahrijouti.com/index.php/posts/index).

I have checked and the rewrite module is on.

Can you please help me with that ?

Comment: Did you configure routes?

Comment: Yes, I think i found the source of my issue, I deployed the project on a linux shared hosting and it works just fine. but when i deploy on the windows shared hosting, it seems like the url rewriting stops working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look on [CakePHP default routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#default-routing). And don't forget to fix all your links.

Answer (score 1):

Your links should have proper addresses. Just look on your Posts's link. These are like this `http://fme.tahrijouti.com/index.php/posts/posts/view/2` but it should be `http://fme.tahrijouti.com/index.php/posts/view/2`. Remember after your host name there exist controller then a function of that controller then argument of that function like this: `[host]/[controller]/[function]/[argument1]/[argument2]`. Hope it helps. I think you can read cookbook another bit as most things are clear there from my experience.

As I don't have your codes of controller I cannot say more.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick answer, actually, I think i wasn't clear on my question.

The issue is that I can't access my controllers by the url : fme.tahrijouti.com/posts, if I do that I have the 404 error, can you tell me how to fix that please ?

Comment: You somehow restricted PostsController(maybe denied allow or anything else). I can't say without seeing your code.

Comment: Hello,You can find my post controller in here : http://sharetext.org/5GcT
Let me just remind you that it's working in my localhost.